# Battery sizing question

Tags: batteries, dc-motor, 12v

I’ve got a 12 VDC vibration motor. It wants 2.1 A, listed as 30 W.

I’ve also got a 12 V, 12Ah battery I know to be in good working order. Initial current is less than 3.6 A.

Is that something that should simply work? I did try hooking it up (I know, possibly a mistake). The meter showed a little over 13 V all the way through past the potentiometer. Tech support guy said dead unit - but I am not sure and need a little expert guidance.

Is there a giant smoking hole in my knowledge of this stuff?

Comment: What potentiometer?  All you described was a battery and a motor.  What unit is the tech guy saying is dead?  The motor?

Comment: Apologies - it adjusts the speed of the motor creating the vibration. Yes the motor. Thanks!

Comment: If it's just motor and battery, likely the motor is dead and nothing to do with the battery. Motors are pretty flexible - 13V on a 12V motor is in all likelihood fine (it will vibrate a little faster and harder than usual).

Comment: I really appreciate the info - it seemed to make sense but I try to stay aware of my limitations! 

I need to get about 2 hrs runtime a day out of the thing, but has to be DC due to being a pretty remote spot. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

12Ah, or 12 ampere-hours rating implies that you can draw 12 amps for a period of 1 hour, or 6 amps for 2 hours or 3 amps for 4 hours etc - until the battery is "discharged" and the voltage goes below acceptable. You see how that works?

However there ARE other considerations regarding how much max current you can draw for optimum operation, and that current depends on the the chemistry/ technology used in that battery.

So to get a better idea about YOUR specific case, you need to find out which type of battery it is - lead acid? LiPo? NiMn? Other  ?